# Command binded to the button is fired twice

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command

Users of my WPF Application from time to time are able to fire twice command that is binded to button.

XAML Code:

```
   <Button x:Name="btnAccept" 
           Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonLarge}"
           Height="42" 
           Command="{Binding Path=SubmitCmd}"
           Content="Submit" />
```

I've got also KeyBindings

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F9" Command="{Binding SubmitCmd}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I am not able to reproduce an error but based on the changes in the database I conclude the command was fired twice one time after time. Is it really posible and how can I prevent such phenomena.
SubmitCmd adds new record to the database and closes form.

Here is the code behind:

```
    vm.SubmitCmd = new RelayCommand(pars => DoSubmit(), pars => vm.CmdSubmitCanExecute, "Submit" );

    private void DoSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!vm.LaunchAllowed)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                vm.LaunchAllowed = false;
                bool isOk = DBService.SaveToDB(vm.Dto);

                if (isOk)
                {
                    DialogResult = true;
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    ShowError(this, result);
                    vm.LaunchAllowed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError(this, ex.Message);
            vm.LaunchAllowed = true;
        }
    }
```

And ViewModel code:

```
    public ICommand SubmitCmd{ get; set; }

    public bool CmdSubmitCanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return LaunchAllowed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a code of the `SubmitCmd`?

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue.
In my case i bind a command into two component, here is the wrong code

```
<pv:PancakeView Grid.Row="3" CornerRadius="30" Margin="24,8,24,16" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MainGreen}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasShadow="True"
                 xct:TouchEffect.PressedOpacity="0.7"
                 xct:TouchEffect.NormalOpacity="1"
                 xct:TouchEffect.AnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicInOut}"
                 xct:TouchEffect.AnimationDuration="100"
                 xct:TouchEffect.PressedScale="0.9"
                 xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding Checkout}">
    <Label Text="CHECKOUT" TextColor="{StaticResource MainWhite}" FontSize="18" FontFamily="{StaticResource PoppinsMedium}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <pv:PancakeView.Shadow>
        <pv:DropShadow Offset="0,0" Opacity="0.15" BlurRadius="25"></pv:DropShadow>
    </pv:PancakeView.Shadow>
    <pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Checkout}"/>
    </pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
</pv:PancakeView>
```

At that xaml code, i bind `Checkout` Command to `TapGestureRecognizer` and `xct:TouchEffect`

Remove one of them solve the problem for me.

for your case, i think below approach will work

In KeyBindings area change the binded command to new command like this `<KeyBinding Key="F9" Command="{Binding OtherSubmitCmd}" />`

Add `public ICommand OtherSubmitCmd{ get; set; }` to your ViewModel. Then assign same methode for `OtherSubmitCmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw this too, but - as you - I was not able to reproduce it. It also was my conclusion.

To solve this I disabled the button right after the command run. So assuming you using mvvm, add a property to it (don't forget to raise the property changed event) and bind the IsEnabled-Property of your button the the new property

Comment: I've alrerady done it. Property LaunchAllowed is such a property. This property controls whether command can be fired or not. Do you think that is not enough (see my ViewModel code)?

Comment: Ok, but you should fire the CanExecuteChanged-Event on the command:

Comment: Do you suggest to place CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() right at start of DoSubmit() procedure?